# How can I make terminal windows show their names?

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, window, titlebar

Is there any way that all terminals can show their name in the title bar, all the time? I can only see a terminal's name when I hover my mouse over that terminal.

[image: A screenshot showing GNOME Terminal windows running in Unity in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, where only the the terminal window that has the pointer hovered over it has any text in its title bar.]

How can I change the default so terminals' names are always shown?

Comment: Hope this help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-can-i-launch-gnome-terminal-with-unique-titles-for-multiple-tabs

Answer (score 0):

That is done in the *system settings*:

There select:

```
Appearance --> Behaviour --> Menus visibility --> Always displayed.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I didn't find Menu visibility under Behavior .I am using ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Do you have a `look` option then.

Comment: Yes I have look option.

Comment: What options are there, and what are under Behaviour ?

Comment: Under look :== (Background , wallpaper , theme , Launcher icon size) and behavior has everything same as you but "Memus visibility " is missing.

Comment: @Avanibadheka if your problem is specific to 15.04 then it is off-topic! please upgrade to a supported release

Answer (score 0):

The best bet I have found is displaying window title at center of thumbnail, I don't know how to display them on their location:

[image]

To achieve this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Open CompizConfig Settings Manager via dash, then do following steps:

1. Search for **Text** and enable the plugin
2. Activate **Scale Addons** plugin under **Utility** area.
3. Go to **Scale Addons** setting, navigate to **Appearance** tab.
4. Under **Window Title** select **All Windows** in the dropdown.